# Git: How to switch branches without touching working directory?

Tags: git, branch, git-branch, git-checkout

I'm working on a temporary branch `foo`. After satisfied with changes, I want to move `master` (which is not current) to the HEAD of `foo`. I think the common way of doing that on Git is this:

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard foo
```

The problem is that when I do `git checkout master`, Git modifies files at working directory and my IDE goes crazy. I have to close it and open again.

My first workaround was this:

```
git branch -D master && git checkout -b master
```

But it makes me loose the upstream setting of `master`. The following actually works:

```
git branch -D master && git checkout -b master && git push --set-upstream origin master
```

But the command is too big.

Is there a better alternative using Git only? i.e. Without add a batch file or macro in the path...

Comment: Almost! I still need to run `git checkout` after updating the branch. But I guess it's better than delete and re-create the branch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
git switch -C master
```

This will move master to point at the current HEAD, keeping any configuration the branch has such as its upstream, then performs `git checkout` to that branch.

Comment: Or, for those who do not have `git switch`, `git checkout -B master`.